# data type mismatch in criteria expression in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to delete a row from ms access database using vb.net.
But I am getting the above mentioned error.
All the fields are text in database.

Here is my code :

```
dim deleteRow() as DataRow

deleteRow = ds.Tables("ccc").Select("Question = '" & QuestionList(x).Text & "'")
deleteRow(0).Delete()
da.Update(ds,"ccc")
```

Comment: What is the content of  `QuestionList(x).Text`? Does it contains a text with a single quote?

Comment: When I try to delete the value of Question(x).Text is 390) What is a computer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vishal.... do any of your questions(x).Text values contain a single quote? The single quotes will cause an error with your select statement. E.G.

> If your question is What's your name?
>   Your select statement would be
>   Select(Question = 'What's your name>?')

This will error at 's  - also I'm not sure if the close bracket will cause an error as in your example above you would have

> Select(Question = '390) What is a Computer ?')

this may error at the first close bracket.

Answer (score 0):

You can try new code snippet

```
Sub DeleteRow()
    Dim cnn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data            Source=MyDatabase.mdb;User Id=admin;Password=;")
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand

    cmd.Connection = cnn
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.CommandText = "DELETE * FROM <your table> WHERE Question='" & QuestionList(x).Text & "'"

    Using cnn
       cnn.open()
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub
```